# IE8 - jquery remove() does not work on a nth element

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

[Please see relevant jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzgzkL9v/1/)

When using:

```
$('element')[1].remove();
```

I am getting that remove() is not a method.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'

In my example I want to remove the second element. And I don't want to assign a unique identifier to each element. How can I use the remove() method properly in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.eq(index)` to extract the element with index 1. By using bracket notation the value which will be extracted is a plain javascript object. It wont contain a function called `.remove()` in it,

```
$('element').eq(1).remove();
```

or

```
$($('element')[1]).remove();
```